# Basic mouseMove horizontal and vertical scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to add javascript in html. But the javascript part didn't work. Here is my full html. Firstly I did it in jsfiddle. It works fine in jsfiddle. I just copy the code and put inside the code.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1254">
<title>Merhaba Dünya!</title>
<script>
var sum = 0;
$("#scroll li").each(function() {
    sum += $(this).width() + parseInt($(this).css('paddingLeft')) + parseInt($(this).css('paddingRight'))
});
$("#scroll").css('width', sum);

$("#holder").mousemove(function(e) {
    x = -(((e.pageX - $('#scroll').position().left) / $("#holder").width()) * ($("#scroll").width() + parseInt($("#scroll").css('paddingLeft')) + parseInt($("#scroll").css('paddingRight')) - $("#holder").width()));

    $("#scroll").css({
        'marginLeft': x + 'px'
    });

    y = -(((e.pageY - $('#scroll').position().left) / $("#holder").width()) * ($("#scroll").width() + parseInt($("#scroll").css('paddingTop')) + parseInt($("#scroll").css('paddingBottom')) - $("#holder").width()));

    $("#scroll").css({
        'marginTop': y + 'px'
    });
});

</script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ornek.css" />
</head>
<body>
            <div id="holder"><ul id="scroll">
        <div class="si"></div>
        <li><div class="si"></div></li><ul>  <li><div class="si"></div></li><ul>
        <li><div class="si"></div></li><ul>
        </ul><div class="si"></div><div class="si"></div><div class="si"></div>
            </ul></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can replace the code inside your each function with `sum += $(this).outerWidth()`. This handy method will calculate the L/R padding for you.

Answer (score 1):

Add your script at the end of the HTML or in a document.ready function.
You try to reach selectors which are not yet loaded.

Comment: I'll try. Thank you for help.